# ESP32C3 Flash memory overflow

Tags: esp32, flash-memory

I 'm using ESP32C3 to develop function including: connect to wifi and bluetooth as well. So far, With Wifi connection function, It worked well and available update OTA via websocket
And now, I'm adding bluetooth function but I faced problem that flash memory of device is overflow. I try customize partitions table as below but look like It was over 4MB of device. If I try add more code mybe, size of bin file will be more and can't upload to device
So Please give me advise for this case. Thanks so much

My partitions table:

## ESP-IDF Partition Table

> Name  Type  SubType  Offset  Size  Flags
>
> - nvs  data  nvs  0x9000  16K
> - OTA Data  data  ota   8K
> - phy_init  data  phy   4K
> - factory   app  factory    0x14173A
> - ota 0     app   ota_0      0x14173A
> - ota 1     app ota_1     0x14173A

Error:

> Error: All app partitions are too small for binary project-name.bin
> size 0x184e30:
>
> - Part 'factory' 0/0 @ 0x10000 size 0x14173a (overflow 0x436f6)
> - Part 'ota 0' 0/16 @ 0x160000 size 0x14173a (overflow 0x436f6)
> - Part 'ota 1' 0/17 @ 0x2b0000 size 0x14173a (overflow 0x436f6) ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

1. Try seprate paritions table but not good solution because If I add more feature to project,memory will overflow because Flash of ESP32 only 4MB
2. Try change config in menuconfig but not help

Answer (score 2):

Your current partition table splits your Flash into 3 equal parts: 1 for the "factory" fallback image and 2 for OTA partitions, each 1.25 MiB. Your image is 1.5 MiB and doesn't fit. You have two options - buy a board with bigger Flash or re-organize the Flash so it has fewer partitions. E.g. lose the "factory" partition and you have space for 2 OTA partitions 1.8 MiB each.